# If $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and $H \cap K = \{e\}$, prove that $G \approx$ a subgroup of $G/H \oplus G/K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and $H \cap K = \{e\}$, prove that $G \approx$ a subgroup of $G/H \oplus G/K$.

I see that any subgroup is of the form $\{(gB,gC): g \in G\}$ where $B$ and $C$ are subsets of $H$ and $K$, respectively, but from here I can't see how to modify this to become an isomorphism.  I tried using the first isomorphism theorem but I couldn't figure how to find the kernel for the homomorphism.

Comment: It's useful to always be aware of "canonical" maps. Given any group $G$ and normal subgroup $H$, there is a *canonical* projection map $G\to G/H$. Given any two group homomorphisms $\alpha:G\to A$ and $\beta:G\to B$, there is a *canonical* "diagonal" map $G\to A\times B$ given by $g\mapsto(\alpha(g),\beta(g))$. In this instance, this means there is a canonical map $G\to G/H\times G/K$ just ready to be investigated.

Comment: And as Michael said, $gB$ is not an element of $G/H$ (when $B\subset H$ is a proper subset), so that's a pretty fundamental misunderstanding of what a quotient group $G/H$ is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true that any subgroup of $G/H\oplus G/K$ is of the form $\{(gB,gC):g\in G\}$ where $B\subset H$ and $C\subset K$. In fact this doesn't even make sense if $B$ is a proper subset of $H$, because $gB$ is not an element of $G/H$ (which consists of cosets of $H$).

To solve the problem, define a map $\varphi:G\to G/H\oplus G/K$ by
$$
\varphi(g)=(gH,gK).
$$
If $\varphi(g)=(H,K)$ then $gH=H\implies g\in H$ and $gK=K\implies g\in K$. Can you finish the proof from here?